# Difference between parentheses and square bracket in objective-c

Tags: objective-c

This might sound dumb but why some functions/methods in Objective-C use parentheses rather than square brackets?

E.g. why it's not [someObject NSLog: @"Hello World!"];?

And when should I use parentheses but not square brackets? Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Parentheses are used for C functions (like CGRectMake) while brackets are used for objective-c methods.

See example:

```
// Method to create C Structure
CGRect frame = CGRectMake( 0, 0, 100, 100 );

// Objective-C method call (sending message)
UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
```

Comment: Thanks dtuckernet. So even it has got NS prefix it's not necessarily Objective-C methods...

Comment: Correct.  NSMakeRect (for OS X development) is an example of a C function with an NS prefix.

Comment: Parenthesis are also used for macros, which look like function calls.